# Theorema: If $E$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $E$ is an algebraic extension of $F$.

Tags: ring-theory

## Theorema:

If $E$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $E$ is an algebraic extension of $F$.

Proof.

Let $α ∈ E$, and let $n = [E : F]$. Then $1,α,α^2,...,α^n$ are $n + 1$ vectors in an
$n$-dimensional vector space, so they must be linearly dependent. Thus $α$ is a root of a
nonzero polynomial with coefficients in $F$, which means that $α$ is algebraic over $F$

Hi,, I just have 1 ask,,

Why $1,α,α^2,...,α^n$  must be linearly dependent??

Comment: It says there in the second sentence, $n+1$ vectors in an $n$-dimensional space.

Comment: This is the definition of $[E:F] = n$ : if $a_1, \ldots,a_{n+1} \in E$ then they are not linearly independent over $F$, that is one of them is a $F$ linear combination of the other :  $a_j = \sum_{i=1,i \ne j}^{n+1} c_i a_i$ with $c_i \in F$

Answer (score 2):

In a finite dimensional space, there are  many characterizations of a basis.

1)  A spanning linearly independent set.

2) A maximal linearly independent set.

3) A maximal orthonormal set.

The second condition, is the important one for us. You are given the set $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^n\}$. This set has $n+1$ elements.

By definition of dimension, every basis of the given space has $n$ elements. But then, a basis, by the second definition, is a maximal linearly independent set. That means, any set with cardinality larger than $n$ must have linearly dependent elements, and since $n+1>n$, $\{ 1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \ldots, \alpha^n\}$ must have linearly dependent elements.